# Add file in a sub directory of a zip

Tags: shell, terminal, gnome-terminal, zip

I have a zip `base.zip` and inside the file there is 2 subdirectory.

```
base.zip
├── subA
│   └── fileA1.txt
│ 
├── subB
│   └── fileB2.jpg
│ 
└── k.jpg
```

I want to add a file in the subA without extract the base.zip and create a new one zip file, i need to do in the terminal.
I read that I can update a zip file with the command

`zip -ur base.zip test.txt`

But with this command the file is just add to the main directory in the zip file.
How can I do from terminal?It's possible to do because one time I just added a file in a sub directory but with the Archivie Manager on the desktop.

Comment: what I usually do is create a folder with the same name that is inside the zip, add the file that I what to add to the zip file to it and then execute the zip command. `zip base.zip subA` because the zip already exists it will add me the file to the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subdirectory named `subA` in your current directory. Put the file you want to add in that subdirectory.

```
mkdir subA
cp -p file-to-add.txt subA
```

Then execute:
`zip base.zip subA/file-to-add.txt`